# Turning on compiler optimizations in visual studio 2008 pro

Tags: visual-c++

How do i change compiler optimizations in visual c++ 2008 pro? I found the instructions for doing it in visual studio 2006 but it seems different than from 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project > NameOfProject Properties... > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Optimization